# How do I make Jenkins fileCopyOperation copy all files including those starting with a dot

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that copy all my source files unfortunately it skip one file named ".DS_store" I have be unable to locate sufficient detailed documentation to figure how to <strike>include hidden files</strike> control details on what files to include. The best I could find is: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/

```
    def CopyJobs = [:]

    def include = Include(Target)

    // copy all folders to c:\svn\vs\... for building there
    for(int i = 0; i< include.size(); i++){
        def index = i
        CopyJobs["CopyJob${i}"] = {
                Run.dir("D:\\Svn\\vs\\")
                {
                    def includeItem = "${include[index]}\\**"
                    Run.echo "CopyJobs ${index} ${includeItem}"
                    Run.fileOperations([
                        Run.fileCopyOperation(excludes: '', flattenFiles: false, includes: "${includeItem}", targetLocation: "C:\\Svn\\vs\\")
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
    Run.parallel CopyJobs
```

---

Edit:
The puzzle has increased I assumed that the problem was the starting dot (.) but I have another file starting with dot that gets copied without problems. That is however not binary but other binaries not starting with dot gets copied ok